# Automatic domain class and parser generation from specification

Tags: java, parsing, protocol-buffers, code-generation, thrift

I have a drone which sends sensor telemetry data to my PC. On my PC a ground station app that I have developed reads this text data and parses it into useful java objects that go into a UI for charts, tables etc.

My problem is that the data format coming from the drone is continuously evolving as I add more and more state and debugging information. I hence end up re-coding the java classes and also the associated parser that I have written using `Scanner`. Below is the data I get from the drone

```
{  ms  5  gy  -0.14  1.32  -1.04  ac  -2.40  3.24  -106.67  acfil  -2.40  3.29  -107.53  ang  -0.93  1.83  -2.30  rc6  1  1  1  6  1  motor  1000  1000  1000  1000  pid  1  100  0  0  -100  0  -3  0  }
{  ms  5  gy  -0.14  1.32  -1.04  ac  -2.12  2.96  -107.43  acfil  -2.25  3.63  -107.53  ang  -2.09  0.33  -17.55  rc6  1  1  1  6  1  motor  1000  1000  1000  1000  pid  1  100  0  0  -100  0  -3  0  }
```

`{` and `}` denote start and end of packet. Abbreviated text like `gy` for gyro and `ac` for accelerometer tells sensor type followed by its value for each axis

A snippet of the parser

```
case "ms":
 if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
     timedelta = scanner.nextDouble();
 }
 break;
case "gy":
 if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
     gX = scanner.nextDouble();
 }
 if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
     gY = scanner.nextDouble();
 }
 if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
     gZ = scanner.nextDouble();
 }
 break;
```

And the domain class

```
public static final class SensorData {

  //internal
  public double frame;
  //time
  public double timestamp, delta;
  //raw gyro+accelerometer
  public double gX, gY, gZ, aX, aY, aZ;
  //raw receiver
  public double rcRoll, rcPitch, rcYaw, rcThrottle, rcMode;
  //computed filtered accelerometer + absolute angle
  public double filaX, filaY, filaZ;
  public double absX, absY, absZ;
  //motor commands
  public double motorFL, motorFR, motorRR, motorRL;
  //PID
  double pitchP, pitchI, pitchD;
  double rollP, rollI, rollD;
  double yawP, yawD;
  .
  .
```

[Full code available here](https://github.com/AeroZealous/GroundStation/blob/master/src/ground/station/SerialDevice.java)

So I need a library that will automatically generate the domain class as well as the parser based on a specification I give.
I cannot use binary serialization format in my project. But I am ready to adopt a different text format.
I have so far come across Google Protocol Buffers which can generate parser and domain classes and I'm investigating its text serialization format.
Apache Thrift is similar but lacking documentation.
I want to know what other alternatives are there or how is this stuff generally done.
I tried searching a lot but google doesnt give me exact hits.

Comment: Why don't you use JSON for the text transport?

Comment: I can use JSON though I am not familiar with Jackson or GSon yet. I think I would just lose data types then and will have to manually check whether an object contains acceleration coordinates or motor commands and so

Comment: "*Apache Thrift is [...] lacking documentation*" -- [wrong](https://www.manning.com/books/the-programmers-guide-to-apache-thrift), [wrong](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/) and [wrong](http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/).

Comment: Its lacking documentation about the format for storing serialized data. There is an unofficial specification [here](https://erikvanoosten.github.io/thrift-missing-specification/) which is all about binary data. I need plain text so thrift seems to be out of the question

Comment: "_lose data types_" how does your homegrown wire protocol ensure data types better than JSON? You need to ask "is this string a double number?" in any case. The advantage of JSON is being _map_, randomly accessible by key, as contrary to your fixed linear ordering of elements.

Comment: I couldn't answer this without falling into the trap of recommending something about which I have an opinion. So I'm voting to close as off-topic: questions asking us to "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow". Sorry.

Comment: I wasn't talking about losing data types in the transport protocol, but in the programming part. Like parsing Json with Jackson  would give me `JsonNode`s everywhere instead of say `GyroSample` or `TimingMetadata`. I then came across `ObjectMapper` in Jackson that would convert those `JsonNode`s to POJOs so that will do fine for me. I guess I should close the question then!